# TomCat 6: can welcome page be inside WEB-INF?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I'm following this example to get Spring up & running: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part2.html

What they do is move all .jsp files inside the WEB-INF, to stop users accessing them directly... so far so good. However the servlet has a welcome page of index.jsp, and when this is moved inside the WEB-INF dir I get errors. I can't determine if Tomcat 6 should allow the welcome page to be inside WEB-INF or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing inside WEB-INF can be directly accessed, but must first pass through something else (usually a servlet), which then forwards the request internally to the WEB-INF resource.

Answer (score 3):

I am trying the same tutorial. The tutorial doesn't say this but I changed the  value in my web.xml from "index.jsp" to "/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp".

Answer (score 1):

I use such technique (which work for Servlet API >= 2.4):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/index.htm</url-pattern>    <<==  *1*
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>   <<== *2*
</welcome-file-list>
```

so you no longer need `redirect.jsp` with:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("/myproject/MyAction.action"); %>
```

in non-`WEB-INF` directory!!

Here two blogs with same technique:

- http://technologicaloddity.com/2010/03/25/spring-welcome-file-without-redirect/
- http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/HowToUseAServletAsYourMainWebPage

**UPDATE** From `SRV.9.10 Welcome Files` section of `Servlet API 2.4` documentation^

```
The purpose of this mechanism is to allow the deployer to specify an ordered
list of partial URIs for the container to use for appending to URIs when there is a
request for a URI that corresponds to a directory entry in the WAR not mapped to
a Web component. This kind of request is known as a valid partial request.

The use for this facility is made clear by the following common example: A
welcome file of `index.html' can be defined so that a request to a URL like
host:port/webapp/directory/, where `directory' is an entry in the WAR that is
not mapped to a servlet or JSP page, is returned to the client as `host:port/
webapp/directory/index.html'.
```

Comment: This answer assumes Spring, but nothing in the question indicates that OP is using Spring.

Comment: Why? It based on `SRV.9.10 Welcome Files` section of Servlet API 2.4 documentation. There are no *Spring* keyword...

Comment: `dispatcher` on `/` is classic Spring.

Comment: Yes I copy part from my Spring project (*as real word example*). But you can do this with any servlets and any servlet mapping URL patterns...

Comment: Oh? Alter the answer accordingly then to achieve it without any 3rd party framework. As far as we know, this is not possible without a servlet which forwards to the `/WEB-INF` resource, like as Spring's dispatcher one, exactly as already answered by skaffman for long.

Comment: Ok, I become understand what you mean )) But in term of Servlet documentation *pages* are not *files* but a way to remap directory entries to another URLs...