# How do I change the location of index.jsp in a war file

Tags: java, web-applications, web.xml

I have the following project structure:

myproject
- src
- WebContent
   - META-INF
   - WEB-INF
      - jsp
        - index.jsp
      - lib
        - web.xml

If my index.jsp comes under the WebContent directory then all is well, but I want it to be under WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp with all the other jsps. What do I have to add to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of WEB-INF aren't publicly accessible resources, why are you putting the other jsps there? Are those other jsps accessible?

If you want to hide the index.jsp, create a servlet mapped to the root path and have it forward to index.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this question [TomCat 6: can welcome page be inside WEB-INF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489219/tomcat-6-can-welcome-page-be-inside-web-inf)

Looks like it can't be done.