# Spring welcome-file-list correct mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know that in spring I must define welcome-file, which should be outside of WEB-INF folder, so I define it like this:

web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But actually my real code is in WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp

So I always have to do this:

```
<jsp:forward page="/index"></jsp:forward>
```

And in my controller this means:

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("contact", new Contact());
    map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());

    return "contact";
}
```

How can I make it this way, that welcome-file always goes to my index mapping, which leads to contact.jsp?

Feel free to ask questions, if this was confusing...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping({"/index", "/"})
```

and

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

worked for me.

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring', updated first post(added servlet-mapping in web.xml).

Comment: It worked, thanks! Is it reasonable thing to do, or I should usually have welcome-file?

Answer (score 4):

See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551678/173149 or just:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/index.htm</url-pattern>    <<==  *1*
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>   <<== *2*
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of java configuration you can override two methods in class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("/index");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

If you wanna serve index.html explicitly, turn it into a resource override a method in the same class as below:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/index.html");
}
```

Of course `addResourceLocations` must follows the folder choosen to hold your views.

See [these samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/server/samples/context/WebConfig.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring', updated first post(added servlet-mapping in web.xml).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your workflow as below:

Basically your web application will look into welcome page and /redirect is fired which is captured by controller and execute the logic;

In web.xml add the following code and drop the `index.jsp` in webapp directory.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In `index.jsp` , add below code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:redirect url="/redirect"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally in the `Controller` , you could add the code below:

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myMethod(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
       // add your logic here
     return "results"; // return results.jsp if you need; 
    }
}
```