# Using @RequestMapping as default welcome file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415084/spring-welcome-file-list-correct-mapping) that I could use the below example to define a default controller/page

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/content/edit", "/"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Unfortunately it's not working.  When I open my app it shows a 404 error unless I look for `/content/edit.htm`

my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your servlet is mapped to "*.htm". "/" does not match that pattern, so your servlet and thus your controller has no chance of being invoked. I think you can specify the welcome file (that's what / is) in web.xml, I would have to look up how, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem this in that **"/content/edit.htm"** is not mapping for

> @RequestMapping(value={"/content/edit", "/"},
>   method=RequestMethod.GET).

You need

> @RequestMapping(value={"/content/edit.htm", "/"},
>   method=RequestMethod.GET).

or

> @RequestMapping(value={"/content/edit.*", "/"},
>   method=RequestMethod.GET).

You can choose the last option because you filter web.xml to *. htm