# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userBean' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am trying to use Spring forms, but getting below exception, I couldn't find anything  wrong in the code and stuck at this for a long time:

```
May 16, 2014 11:51:08 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag
SEVERE: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userBean' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userBean' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(login_jsp.java:156)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:111)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:70)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
May 16, 2014 11:51:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userBean' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(login_jsp.java:156)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:111)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:70)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Below is my **login.jsp** page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form:form action="/login" commandName="userBean" method="post"  >
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td><td><form:input path="username"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td><td><form:input path="password"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form> 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

controller class **SampleController.java**

```
package com.infy.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class SampleController {

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(ModelMap m){
    System.out.println("viewing the login page.");
    UserBean userBean=new UserBean();
    m.addAttribute("userBean",userBean);
    return "login";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("userBean")UserBean userBean){

    System.out.println("Submitting the form");
    return "loginSuccess";
}
}
```

**UserBean.java**

```
package com.infy.controller;

public class UserBean {

private String username;
private String password;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

**Web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
   <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <servlet id="dispatcherServlet">
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and **dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
       ">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.infy"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />       
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

If i don't use the form tag in login.jsp then the page is rendering properly. So I don't think anything is wrong with configurations.
I am using "userBean" as commandName in form,and adding that in my controller with the same name, I don't understand why it is throwing this exception.
Please help!

Edit: New web.xml with added welcome-file-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
   <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <servlet id="dispatcherServlet">
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Comment: Try replacing `commandName="userBean"` of `<form:form>` by `modelAttribute="userBean"`.

Comment: @Tiny: Tried,but getting same exception :(

Comment: Solved the problem :)

Comment: Pleased :) How? Please answer your own question.

Comment: @Tiny : Solved the problem :),but again 2 questions :(  how I solved it: I did not changed anything in the code, instead 

of opening **login.jsp** I typed **login** and I don't know why but it is working!! First question, can you tell me why 

**login.jsp** is not working? Second question , in Web.xml I have defined Welcome-page but that is not working. After 

running the project I had to type every time /l

Comment: `login.jsp` doesn't work because you're using a RESTful / annotated controller wherein you map URLs like so `@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)`. This is precisely handled by `dispatcherServlet` which you configure in `web.xml`. In the current code snippets, you have specified `<welcome-file-list>` in a wrong file - `dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml` (not in `web.xml`)

Comment: @Tiny thank you for the clarification. I have moved '<welcome-file-list>' from 'dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml' to 'web.xml' ,still same problem.

Comment: Where did you put `login.jsp` (it should only be `login` in `web.xml`)? If it is under `WEB-INF` then, it is inaccessible. You have to move it outside of this folder as a welcome page. Check to see, there should be an incorrect path. [More](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7415084/1391249).

Comment: Thank you @Tiny for help. That link was useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem and here are the answers for your two questions

1) In SpringMVC the flow starts from controller to Jsp not JSP to controller. In your browser whatever request you type , it will point to controller class only. Here in your controller the  @RequestMapping attribute path is "/login" that's equal to what you typed in the browser that's why it worked.

2) In SpringMVC in order to access any view (JSP file) which is  inside WEB-INF can be done via controller only. i.e you can't call a jsp file inside WEB-INF directly from the browser that's why even you specify in that login.jsp in welcome-list it didn't worked

Hope it will clear your doubts