# controller desn't get executed when I set value of @RequestMapping to "/"

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want map root path of the application to a specific controller. Below is how I did this:

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class Index {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String indexPage(ModelMap model, @CookieValue(value = "cityName", defaultValue = "beijing") String cityNameCookie, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String cityName = CookieTools.setCityNameValue(request, cityNameCookie);
        model.addAttribute("cityName", cityName);
        System.out.println("index");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>


   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I enter the localhost:8080, the controller is not executed as expected. 
I try to change `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, and enter localhost:8080/abc, the controller get executed as expected.

So I think the problem is on the syntax of @requestMapping value attribute.

So, my Question is **How to map root path using requestMapping?**

I googled the relative keyword but found nothing.

Comment: It works fine for me, which server you are using? If tomcat, what is the project name deployed inside webapps folder?

Comment: Do you have another controller mapped to '/' ?

Comment: @javaguy I use tomcat and intellij idea. My project name is jiaotong but I deployed it in root context of tomcat.

Comment: silly question, just check if it works at `localhost:8080/abc` even after mapping to `@RequestMapping(value = "/")`

Comment: @utkusonmez No, I had another controller mapped to '/', But I delete it and rerun application, still got the same problem.

Comment: can you try with "http://localhost:8080/" ?

Comment: @javaguy I got 404 when access localhost:8080/abc after mapping to @RequestMapping(value = '/')

Comment: @utkusonmez I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Everything seems fine actually, do you run new code? when you change to "/", can you try with "localhost:8080/abc"?

Comment: localhost:8080 shouldn't work. It's localhost:8080/Appname

Comment: solved. see the first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415084/spring-welcome-file-list-correct-mapping

Answer (score 0):

Please add @RequestMapping(value = "/") annotation to your controller and then try.

Here is working example for me,

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

Spring config,

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved. see the first answer of [Spring welcome-file-list correct mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415084/spring-welcome-file-list-correct-mapping)

add

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

to my web.xml.

worked for me.